# Is there a word for when someone is telling you to do something when it is obvious that you were going to do said thing anyway

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I had a room mate who would always tell me to do stuff like clean the kitchen after I had used it, or clean up after I'd spilled something. It was obvious in each situation that I was going to do said thing anyway.

Is there a specific word or phrase for such behavior? Other than "bossy".

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a word or phrase for that, I don't think. You could say that the person is "stating the obvious," but that doesn't imply being bossy or nagging as the other answer suggests.

A common reply to this person might be the expression, "duh!" It's very informal, but it's a very short word that means the same as "what do you think, I'm stupid?"

Answer (score 0):

The usual term for this activity is **nagging**, and the person doing it is **a nag**. But there is no implication that the person being nagged was definitely going to do the things anyway. I can't think of a single word that conveys that. I might say something like "they are nagging me needlessly" or "... for no reason."

Answer (score 0):

I would tell them they were ***making a superfluous request***.

Or if you wanted to add a further touch you could say that their ***superfluidity went beyond reason, since it should be perfectly obvious to anyone with a modicum of common sense that you were the sort of person who would clean up after yourself***.